Angular signals input effects
I have a component in angular with this 3 signal input:

  initialPrice = input<number | undefined>();
  maxValue = input<number>(999999999);
  minValue = input<number>(0);

I want to trigger in effects whenerver an input changes and trigger a functions:
      effect(() => {
        this.handleNormalizeChange();
        this.updateFormattedCurrentPrice();
        this.updateValidators(this.minValue(), this.maxValue());
      });

Question: how can i trigeer just 1 function if the releted input changes and not all the functions every time effect is executed?
I want basically the functionality of ngOnChanges with previousValue and currentValue.
thanks

will 3 effects with one function call work for you?

Signals only fire when the value changes, so you don't need this check at all.
Effect also triggers only when the signals inside it changes.
So when the effect fires you can be certain, that the actual value has changed inside the signal.
This is true for all primitive types (number, boolean, etc). For reference types like array or object we can update the inner values without firing the signal, so we need to be careful here, but looking at the signals provided, that is not the case.
constructor() {
    effect(() => {
        this.handleNormalizeChange();
        this.updateFormattedCurrentPrice();
    });

    effect(() => {
        this.updateValidators(this.minValue(), this.maxValue());
    });
}

